# Hide and Show Table Rows according to what is typed into Search Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a table with multiple tr under tbody under a table with #attribute.

```
function searchEnter() {
    var content = $('#search').val();
    $('#search').change(function() {
        if ($('#search').text() != content) {
            content = $('#search').val();
            $('tbody', '#attribute').each(function() {
                $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
                    if ($('tbody>tr>h4:contains(' + content + ')')) {
                        $(this).show();
                    } else {
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    });
}
```

I wanted to change the contents of the table according to what is typed into the search box. Though I'm also not sure about how to structure the html for the search box (also using Twitter Bootstrap) or if the jquery/javascript is right. Also not sure what the action should be but I wanted it to refer to the function and not a PHP file.

```
<form class="well form-search fill pull-right" action="">
      <input id="search" type="text" class="input-medium search-query"  />
      <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="searchEnter">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var search$ = $('#search')
    , table$ = $('#mytable')
    , content = search$.val().toLowerCase();

  search$.change(function() {
    if (search$.val() === content) { return; }
    content = search$.val().toLowerCase();

    table$.find('tr').show();

    table$
      .find('h4')
       .filter(function (index, element) { 
           return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(content) === -1; })
      .closest('tr')
      .hide();    
  });

});​
```

I also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsP5a/) to demonstrate and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsP5a/1/) that works on a key up event which is even nicer.

Comment: @Marisa: Did you try the proposed solution?

Comment: Im trying it now. Though I get the feeling I'm using it wrong. 
The form action is not specified and so when I click the search button it just refreshes the page.

Comment: @Marisa: Do you need to go to the server? Otherwise remove the form and the type='submit' from the button.

Comment: Aha, that' was the problem with form. yeah I didnt need to go to the server. I got rid of form now. Though, now when I click the search button it says that searchEnter cannot be found. Are there extra parenthesis in your answer?

Comment: @Marisa: By using the change event on textbox the code will be triggered when you leave the textbox. If you want to trigger the search only when you click the button the code must change. The code in my answer runs immediately and attaches it self to the textbox. Otherwise you would register the change event on every click. So you need to decide if you want to search when you leave the field or when you click the button.

Comment: @Marisa: Any update? If you run my code on your page and you type in the search field and leave it should filter your rows.

Comment: it doesn't filter the rows at all actually. idk why. Should  I use keyup instead? (does this actually work for you?)

Comment: @Marisa I fixed the code example above and added a JSFiddle. Sorry there was a bug in the code.

Comment: It's not filtering through it as I type for some odd reason.
says that this is undefined: search$.val().toLowerCase();
And I know that it's undefined because I havent typed anything but even when i do it doesnt register for some reason. Is it because I have to set the display: blocked, for the css?

Comment: @Marisa It is 'display:block' instead of 'blocked' and that isn't your problem. The problem is that #search can not be found. So two things: 1. Did you properly set the id to 'search'? 2: Put all your code in $(document).ready(function () { /* your code in here */ }).
I've updated the example above.

Comment: This is more of what I'm trying to work with http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/2/ Im trying to hide the whole row as as you can see as I type it doesn't change at all

Comment: @Marisa There were two problems with your fiddle. One was that you didn't select jQuery from the dropdownlist in the left panel. The other problem was that you commented out the line where content was declared. I've updated your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/YxU2H/11/) and it works for me now. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector just for the row, which is probably a cleaner way to start. So in your code, after you determine new text has been entered, start a block with something like:

```
$('tr').each(function(index){
```

Which will select all your rows. If you have TR elements in more than just this table, you could either specify each with a class, such as 'table_row' or specify the table itself with an id, such as 'data_table'

```
$('.table_row').each(function(index){ //Class based selector
$('#data_table tr').each(function(index){ //Id based selector
```